# R: geom_text label does not recognize numeric character

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I created a graph with ggplot2 and I have this code which works well enough.

```
ggp <- ggplot(data.frame(diam.split.data$"(0,10]"),aes(x=intcat))
ggp + geom_bar() + 
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=paste(round(..count../151*100),"%")), vjust=-1)
```

[image]

However, I need to change the 151 (the total observations for this dataset) manually each time I create a different graph. So I came up with this line which gives me the 151 (and which also works with each different dataset):

```
f1 <- (as.numeric(substr(((unname((summary(diam.split.data$"(0,10]"))))[1,1]), 
  start=9, stop=20)))
```

No problem here. f1 gives 151 the same way f1 <- 151 does.

BUT when I try to substitute the 151 in the ggplot2 code, it fails:

> Error in paste(formula = round(count/f1 * 100), "%") : object 'f1' not found

How do I tell R to use f1 as a standard numeric value (the same thing it's been doing with 151)?

Comment: Maybe you just wanted `..ncount..` instead...?

Comment: Pls. provide reproducible data input into ggplot2.  It's not clear to me you need to calculate f1 this way, when you can do (..count..)/sum(..count..)

Comment: Ah, `..ncount..` isn't available with that stat.

Comment: Do you have to do the math within ggplot?  perhaps more clean to perform all calculations first then pass the result to ggplot.

Comment: I agree with R.S., and also would point out that, unless I'm misunderstanding you, your calculation of `f1` is a very odd way to arrive at `nrow(diam.split.data)`...?

Comment: Please, supply a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for your fast replies! Joran, yes my calculation of f1 was so complicated for nothing, thanks! Dan Slone, yeah I was looking for a way to do it quickly withtout needing to do the math first, but it is indeed less clean. R.S. (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100 did exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much, and please excuse the poor quality of this post, as this is my first time posting here. I will be more explicit and provide data next time!

Comment: @SergioCortez, would you post an answer below, summarising what has been said in the comments? Thanks if you can find the time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was simply replacing (..count../151*100) with ((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100) as @R.S. suggested. Thanks everyone.